# Trouble setting a uint32 key location and writing it to a file

Tags: c, text, encode, fwrite

I am currently trying to create a file encoder that writes a few lines of text to a .dat file, and outputs the file after running the executable. However there are a few errors keeping me from compiling, I also do not understand how to set the uint32keylocation.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
/*

message pair structure
uint32 size
char * message

file spec:  
char * Header = CS2060 with no null byte
uint32 keylocation
messagePair First Name
messagePair Last Name
messagePair Message 1 = what grade you think you should get in class
messagePair key
messagePair message 2 = go for lol points

    No code needed for assignment, just send the output file (.dat or .bin is an     appropriate file name extension)

*/

int xor(char * in, uint32_t insize, char * pass, uint32_t passSize){
uint32_t i;
for(i = 0; i < insize; i++){
    in[i] = in[i]^pass[i%passSize];
}
return i;
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv){

if(argc != 2){
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s [filename]\n",argv[0]);
    return 1;
}
FILE * fh = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
if(!(fh)){
    fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file\n");
    return 1;
}

char header[7];
uint32_t keyloc;
uint32_t fsize;
uint32_t lsize;
uint32_t keysize;
uint32_t m1size;
uint32_t m2size;
uint32_t realLocation;

char * first;
char * last;
char * key;
char * m1;
char * m2;

fwrite(header, 6, 1, fh);

if(strncmp(header,"CS2060",6)){
    fprintf(stderr,"header is incorrect\n");
    return 2;
}


fread(&keyloc,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fh);
char first[] = 'name';
uint32_t fsize = strlen(first);
fwrite(&fsize,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fh);
fwrite(first,fsize,1,fh);

fread(&keyloc,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fh);
char last[] = 'namee';
uint32_t fsize = strlen(last);
fwrite(&fsize,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fh);
fwrite(last,fsize,1,fh);

fread(&keyloc,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fh);
char m1[] = 'B';
uint32_t fsize = strlen(m1);
fwrite(&fsize,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fh);
fwrite(m1,fsize,1,fh);

fread(&keyloc,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fh);
char key[] = 'The key is H';
uint32_t fsize = strlen(key);
fwrite(&fsize,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fh);
fwrite(key,fsize,1,fh);

fread(&keyloc,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fh);
char m2[] = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ab_channel=RickAstleyVEVO';
uint32_t fsize = strlen(m2);
fwrite(&fsize,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fh);
fwrite(m2,fsize,1,fh);

realLocation = ftell(fh);
fread(&keysize,sizeof(uint32_t),1,fh);
key = (char *)malloc(keysize+1);
fread(key,keysize,1,fh);
key[keysize] = 'H';


printf("First: %s\n",first);
printf("Last: %s\n",last);
printf("m1: %s\n",m1);
printf("m2: %s\n",m2);

if(realLocation == keyloc){
    printf("The location is correct\n");
}else{
    printf("The location is INCORRECT\n");
}









return 0;
}
```

And here is the error message that displays, it is fairly long and I am at a loss about where to start.

```
new2.c: In function ‘main’:
new2.c:69:8: error: conflicting types for ‘first’
char *first[] = 'name';
    ^
new2.c:54:9: note: previous declaration of ‘first’ was here
char * first;
     ^
new2.c:69:18: warning: character constant too long for its type
char *first[] = 'name';
              ^
new2.c:69:2: error: invalid initializer
char *first[] = 'name';
^
new2.c:70:11: error: redeclaration of ‘fsize’ with no linkage
uint32_t fsize = strlen(first);
       ^
new2.c:47:11: note: previous declaration of ‘fsize’ was here
uint32_t fsize;
       ^
new2.c:70:26: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ from incompatible   pointer type
uint32_t fsize = strlen(first);
                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:29:0,
             from new2.c:1:
/usr/include/string.h:33:9: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of     type ‘char **’
 size_t  _EXFUN(strlen,(const char *));
```

This was the error I received for each write block that I made.

EDIT 2: Okay so after some rebuilding from scratch, this is what I have so far which successfully writes. So I think I can keep using this format to write the rest. My only question is what is uint32 keylocation and how do I set it? The instructions seem vague. Also how do I respond directly to comments but still include my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
/*

message pair structure
uint32 size
char * message

file spec:  
char * Header = CS2060 with no null byte
uint32 keylocation
messagePair First Name
messagePair Last Name
messagePair Message 1 = what grade you think you should get in class
messagePair key
messagePair message 2 = go for lol points

No code needed for assignment, just send the output file (.dat or .bin is an appropriate file name extension)

*/

int xor(char * in, uint32_t insize, char * pass, uint32_t passSize){
uint32_t i;
for(i = 0; i < insize; i++){
    in[i] = in[i]^pass[i%passSize];
}
return i;
}

int main(){

FILE * fp;

fp = fopen("HW06.dat","w");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Could not open file\n");
    return 1;
}

char header[7] = "CS2060";
uint32_t keyloc;
uint32_t fsize;
uint32_t lsize;
uint32_t keysize;
uint32_t m1size;
uint32_t m2size;
uint32_t realLocation;

char * first;
char * last;
char * key;
char * m1;
char * m2;


fwrite(header,sizeof(char), 6, fp);


fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay , one question , _why do you declare variables twice_ ?

Comment: `char *first = "name";` or `char first[] = "name";` or `char *first;` then `first = "name";`

Comment: You seem to mistakenly edit my answer instead of your question, friend.

Comment: Oh okay, I'm new to the site and I'm still trying to get a hang of the formatting

Answer (score 1):

One of problems is shown in the error messages pretty well I think, it is redeclaration.

For instance, consider this,

```
char * first;
```

You have declared `first` to be pointer to a `char`, but in the following line

```
char first[] = 'name';
```

You declare it to be an array. This is called re-declaration (shown in your error message). Even re-declare it as `char*` would have been rejected, save re-declare it as a new type (`char` array).

Edit: some more, the declaration above is wrong because single quote `'a'` is used to declare single character. To declare a string (or `char` array in C), use double quotes `"name"`.

You also seem to re-declare `fsize` multiple times (the same issue).

To use/assign the already declared `fsize`, simply put `fsize=something` rather than `uint32_t fsize=something`

The principle is, once you declare a variable, you just need to use it - never re-declare it.

For instance,

```
int a = 67, b = 10; //declared
a = a + b; //use
```

And not

```
int a = 67, b = 10; //declared
int a = a + b; //re-declaration!!!!
```